# Compute Cech cohomology of $CP^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to compute  $H^i (CP^2,Z) $
I want to use Cech Cohomology method
Let $U_1=D (x) $ , $U_2=D (y) $ , $U_3=D (z) $
I am able to get that $C_°(U_i)= Z$
So I got the Cech complex to be
$0\rightarrow Z+Z+Z \rightarrow^g Z+Z+Z\rightarrow^h C_2 (U_{123})\rightarrow^f 0$
I am able to show $H^0= Z $ and $H^1=0$
I guess $C_2 (U_{123})= Z+Z+Z+Z$
But I could not prove it, also could not compute 
$H^2 (CP^2,Z) $
I want to find the $Im h $ to compute it. If anyone can show me the exact map, and how to compute it's image, it would be great. I am doing this just to see how change the sheaf of regular functions to constant sheaf change values of Cech Cohomolgy for Complex Projective Space. Also it would be also great if someone shows me the $RP^2$ over constant sheaf too. Just to have more examples.

Comment: It's a little early in the season, but perhaps the title should have used the near-word "cohomo gy" instead of "coho ology".

Comment: It's fixed, thanks

Comment: Beware that your cover is not "good" for the constant sheaf. In other words, the Cech cohomology with respect to that cover will not yields the usual cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^2$. I believe $C_2(U_{123})=\mathbb{Z}$ and that $h$ is onto. Note that $U_{123}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^4$ without two planes which intersect in a point.